# How can I enable/disable the Send button in an MFMailComposeViewController based on the message body?

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, error-reporting

In my app, when an error occurs, I give the user the option to report what went wrong by emailing a support address.  I prepopulate the body of the email with:

> Please describe what you were doing when the error occurred.

There's a problem somewhere in the app, though I haven't seen it.  I know it's there because I'm getting emails to the support address, but they all just say:

> Please describe what you were doing when the error occurred.

Users, amirite?

So what I'd like to do is to disallow this particular mail body, and not actually enable the "Send" button unless they've edited the message body.  I realise I may just end up with small variations on the existing body, but hopefully at least some of the users will get the hint.

I've looked in `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` but there's no appropriate method for doing this.  Is there a way to achieve this using `MFMailComposeViewController` or do I need to write a replacement?

Comment: Can't be done. There is no public API to support this with `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Comment: You need to write something yourself. *MFMailComposeViewController* is Apple's ViewController. They don't want you to mess around with it, and play with the user's experience. You're better off creating a simple modal ViewController with some input text (you can fully control the input), and send the information another way (via a web-service maybe ?).

Comment: @rdurand The reason for using mail is that the user might be reporting that they can't contact our web service.  It really needs to be something that doesn't rely on our server (or even on having network access right now) and that will be queued for later use even if the user doesn't open our app again.

Comment: Oh, ok. No webservice then. Testflight used to offer a similar functionality. You could add their SDK and prompt the user on demand. But they closed the access to their SDK since Apple bought the parent company. Maybe there is something out there that could do the same ?

Comment: [UserVoice](https://www.uservoice.com/mobile/) or [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/features) may suit your needs !